# why instance.profile.save()

Tags: python, django

I have some trouble understanding this code.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Why do we need to execute `instance.profile.save()` here, given that `post_save` signal is a proof that the user is already saved and a profile associated that user is already created?

Please help me understand it! Thanks

edit:
in `instance.profile.save()` is `profile` a built-in keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the first signal is to create the profile when the user is created. The second one to update the user and profile in one call, for example:

```
user.first_name = 'John'
user.last_name = 'Smith'
user.profile.age = 30
user.save()  # user and profile are updated in one call
```

so you don't have to do:

```
user.profile.save()
```

Comment: Honestly, the second signal is an overkill to avoid writing one line of code.